# Oracle VirtualBox for Ubuntu detecting avx & avx2 for one CPU but not the other

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, kvm

I have been looking into this issue for days now. In short, Oracle VirtualBox started supporting avx & avx2 since version 5.0.3. Right now, it's on 6.1.16, so way ahead.

I had many problems installing TensorFlow in my VirtualBox Ubuntu on this desktop with Intel Core i7 4790K. I boiled it down after a lot of investigation into avx/avx2 not being enabled in the guest. My CPU flags prove this when I type `more /proc/cpuinfo | grep flags` into the bash shell.

I have already looked at possible solutions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543874/avx-inside-a-virtualbox-vm), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699077/how-to-enable-avx2-extensions-on-a-ubuntu-guest-in-virtualbox-5), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760794/vboxmanage-setextradata-command-does-not-add-avx2-to-proc-cpuinfo)) and run them. They show `Key: VBoxInternal/CPUM/IsaExts/AVX2 1` as expected. But it still doesn't show up when I type the `more /proc/cpuinfo | grep flags` into the bash shell.

The most important difference from the previous questions is it DOES work and avx(2) DO show up in my newer laptop with i7-8565U and everything works perfectly. I have made sure Intel Virtualization is enabled on my BIOS, switched to KVM Paravirtualization, etc. done everything to make them identical. However, it's not working in my 4790K computer.

Just to clarify, BOTH CPUs support AVX according to their specifications.

Comment: I've got the same problem. It doesn't work on my i7-9750H but it works on my coworker's i7-10750H in the same model laptop as me (just that model a year later hence the different CPU). My i7-9750H does support AVX2. Indeed when I use the git bash shell from my host OS, it reports AVX2 support.

Comment: @JeffWalkerCodeRanger Oh wow. Thank you for confirming. I was thinking it's because my CPU is "old" and the first gen to support AVX. But if it's even happening to a 9th gen, something else is wrong here. What's stranger in your case is both are even the same series ending in H. Mine were between K and U, latter of which is low power I think. But even the series is not important it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with tensorflow. I found out that having Hyper-V enabled in under Windows Features was the problem(host system is Windows 10). After disabling it, I also disabled the Windows subsystem for Linux since I wasn't using it anyway and rebooted my laptop and restarted the Ubuntu 18 VM on VirtualBox (6.1.22).
It automatically recognized the AVX2 capabilities after this.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to have worked!